# How to copy a row in an arraylist and append it in the same arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, copy

the problem I am facing is that I have an arraylist consisting of different rows. Now I want to copy a row and append it in the same arraylist. Now, if I change a value in either of the rows, it's getting reflected in both the rows ans I don't want this. I have already user

> orderList.add(order)

but it's not working the way I want it. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: could you provide the code that you have written?

Comment: YOu must post relevant code and the problem happening with code. You can refer how to ask a question by checking http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and how to create an example by reading this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Copy objects instead of references. Does your class have a copy constructor ?

Answer (score 1):

You may be modifying the object.  Before you readd to the list , create a new instance of the row and copy that value.

> Don't assign the reference of newly allocated memory to the previous row.

For e.g

```
MyObj row = arrList.get(1);
```

now if you add it to the list as following

```
arrList.add ( row ) ;
```

> then any change to `row` will modify both the elements in list.

Rather

```
MyObj newObj = new MyObj ( row );
arrList.add ( newObj ) ;
```

> Now you can change any of the objects independently.